# How to retrieve the document id from within the streambuilder in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firestore, geoflutterfire,and cloudfirestore plugins to capture the nearby items from my current geographical location. I would like to push the document id through to the buildNearbyCard although I cannot figure out how to access this. What am I missing here?

```
StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                      stream: stream,
                      builder: (context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 140,
                            child: ListView.separated(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                itemCount: 5,
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return const SizedBox(width: 15);
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  DocumentSnapshot data =
                                      snapshot.data![index];
                                  GeoPoint documentLocation =
                                      data.get('position')['geopoint'];
                                  var distanceInMeters =
                                      Geolocator.distanceBetween(
                                          center.latitude,
                                          center.longitude,
                                          documentLocation.latitude,
                                          documentLocation.longitude);
                                  var distInMiles =
                                      (distanceInMeters * 0.00062137)
                                          .toStringAsFixed(1);
                                  return buildNearbyCard(
                                    index: index,
                                    titleName: '${data.get('name')}',
                                    distance: '${distInMiles}',
                                    cost: '${data.get('cost')}',
                                    );
                                }),
                          );
                        } else {
```

Below is how I am running the geoflutterfire search for location

```
var ref = _firestore.collection('locations');
    double radius = 40; //radius is set to 40kms
    String field = 'position';
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: ref)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentSnapshot data =
```

This guy has the properties listed here: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html

And one of those is `id`, your document ID.  If that's what you were looking for, it's right in front of you.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, thank you! The answer was quite literally (data.id) - I spent over an hour on something this simple :)